# Empty device list on eclipse while I'm running simple android application

Tags: android

I get empty device list on eclipse although I'm connecting a device with Android 4.2 running on it. How can I add my device to the list?

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I mean real device that is connected to the computer through USB. I don't mean avds.

Comment: Do you have the drivers installed?

Comment: I cannot find the USB driver for my mobile in the Samsung official website. My phone model is: GT-S7582. Do you know how can I find it?

Comment: The solution at this link: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69727/usb-driver-for-samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2/69728#69728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must turn on **USB debugging** on the device, and install the corresponding USB drivers.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: The remaining solution at this link: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69727/usb-driver-for-samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2/69728#69728

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the device is configured to allow 'USB Debug' Connections (in the Developer options on the device).

Sometimes, you will need to restart ADB once the device is connected if it isn't showing up.  To do this, there is a button in the 'DDMS Perspective'\Devices\rightmost upside down triangle button.

Or from the command line:

```
adb kill-server
adn start-server
```